# Flutter shared_preferences getString() not returning a String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am quite new to Flutter, and I am now trying to use its [`shared_preferences`](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value) package for saving a String and retrieving it back.

Now, I believe `getString` should return a String (at least that's what VS Code tells me), so I declared a wrapper function that returns a String:

```
String getName() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('name');
}
```

However, this does not compile, with the error (notice the missing quotation mark of `'String`):

> A value of type 'String can't be returned from method 'getName' because it has a return type of 'String'

If I remove the return type altogether, the error goes away:

```
getName() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('name');
}
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here? What does `getString` actually return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return a `Future` as yours is an async function

```
Future<String> getName() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I now figured out what I was missing: **my function is async!**

And as it turns out, **async function in Dart have a return type of `Future`.**